# Formatting DateTime to yyyy and zero Fill When Null in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, format

I am trying to format a DateTime field into a string with yyyyMMdd format. Here is how the field is extracted.

BirthYear = CASE WHEN AB.BirthDate IS NULL THEN 0000
ELSE AB.BirthDate
END

The string builder looks like this

FORMAT(BirthYear, 'yyyy')

However, I see that null values are outputted as 1900. Any idea how to zero fill the null values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is SQL Server from a few telltales in the question, in which case this turns your birthdate into yyyyMMdd or 00000000 depending:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar, ab.birthdate, 112), '00000000')
```

CONVERT to varchar with pattern 112 turns a date into yyyyMMdd format. If null is passed in, null is returned (format doesn't accept NULL which is why I didn't use it). If null is returned, coalesce will convert it to 00000000

00000000 is not a date; there is no "0th of Nonuary 0000" so it is not a yyyyMMdd string. Use with care

---

ps; the reason why you get 1900 out is because that's when SQLS is programmed to think 0 is in terms of numeric representation of dates/days. You can do e.g. `GetUtcDate() + 1.0` to get this time tomorrow, or `GetUtcDate() - 7.0` to get this time this day, last week or even fractions like `GetUtcDate() + 1.0/24 + 17.0/24/60` to get now plus 1 hour plus 17 minutes, so there is a correlation between numbers and dates, and SQLS is programmed to consider that number 0 and 1900-01-01 are equivalent. -1 is 1899-12-31 etc

Comment: pps: if you manipulate dates by adding numbers, get into the habit of using a decimal number in some part of any operation; `12.0/24` is 0.5 so half a day will be added. `12/24` is 0 and `36/24` is 1 (integer division) so what you think would be added, isn't